# Espresso how to search for text and if text is displayed click on it else continue test

Tags: android, junit4, robotium, android-testing, android-espresso

I want to click on the app tutorial OK button which is displayed only for first time,

In robotium this statement does this

```
if(solo.searchText("OK")){
        solo.clickOnText("OK");
    }else{
        //Do other things
}
```

If OK text is not displayed test should not fail it should continue, but in espresso test is failed when second time app is run because that time app tutorial is not displayed.

In espresso

```
onView(withText("OK")).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

asssertion fails here, I want boolean return value for OK text so that if OK button is not displayed test should continue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807131/espresso-return-boolean-if-view-exists
this question is somewhat related to this conditional testing situation

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public void checkVisibileText(@StringRes int message) {
    onView(withText(message)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)));
}
```