# Return Boolean if element exists

Tags: android, android-espresso

I need to implement in Espresso something like this:

```
if (!onView(withId(R.id.someID)).check(Exist()){
// push button
} else {
 // select check box
}
```

I have checked this post: [Espresso: return boolean if view exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807131/espresso-return-boolean-if-view-exists/20811193#20811193) and would like example how to implement second answer form ValeraZakharov, because I've tried to implement myself but with little success.

Answer (score 1):

example implementation could be

```
public void testSomthing() {
  if (!doesViewExist(R.id.someID)) {
    // push button
  } else {
    // select check box
  }
}

public boolean doesViewExist(int id) {
  try {
    onView(withId(id)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    return true;
  } catch (NoMatchingViewException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  The framework catches the exception & finishes the activity before it can be caught by this code.

Comment: @Gary99 -  Notice the NoMatching is an exception but ViewAssertion is an error. Use the catch(Throwable t) and try it again.